# Generating Classes and Dependencies Dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, oop, dynamic, synthetic, bogus

I am bit new to C# and some of its advanced OOP features.

I am using the Bogus package to generate synthetic data.

Below is a sample code that picks a random value from the parameter list (EventActionsDomainValues) and assigns
it to an attribute in a class (EventSchema) using the synthetic data generation rule defined for this attribute
in syntheticEvent object.

However, I need to make this code fully parameterized as follows:

1. The attribute name (EventAction) for class EventSchema cannot be hard coded. It needs to be read from some string parameter.

```
public class EventSchema
{
    public string? EventAction { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{EventAction} ";
    }
}
```

2. The attribute name (EventAction) and random values input (EventActionsDomainValues) into the synthetic data generation rule cannot be hard coded.
   They need to be read from some rule string parameters.

```
var syntheticEvent = syntheticEventFaker
        .RuleFor(de => de.EventAction, f => f.PickRandom(EventActionsDomainValues))
        .Generate();
```

Current code with hard coded classes:

```
using Bogus;

public class StaticClasses
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // EventActionsDomainValues parameter.
        List<string> EventActionsDomainValues = new List<string>
        {
            "Post", "Patch", "Put", "Get", "Delete"
        };

        var syntheticEventFaker = new Faker<EventSchema>();

        var syntheticEvent = syntheticEventFaker
                .RuleFor(de => de.EventAction, f => f.PickRandom(EventActionsDomainValues))
                .Generate();

        Console.WriteLine(syntheticEvent.ToString());
    }
    public class EventSchema
    {
        public string? EventAction { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{EventAction} ";
        }
    }
}
```

Need help/guidance with points 1 and 2 above. How would the parameterized code look?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need help/guidance with points 1 and 2 above. How would the parameterized code look?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dynamic members and add and remove them at runtime with the ExpandoObject Class. For example:

```
internal class Program
{
    static dynamic CreateDynamicObject()
    {
        return new ExpandoObject();
    }

    static void AddPropertyDynamically(ExpandoObject expandoObject, string propertyName, object propertyValue )
    {
        var dictionary = expandoObject as IDictionary<string, object>;
        dictionary.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
    }

    static void AddMethodDynamically(ExpandoObject expandoObject, string methodName, Func<object> methodValue)
    {
        var dictionary = expandoObject as IDictionary<string, object>;
        dictionary.Add(methodName, methodValue);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create an object with a string property "EventAction"
        // and a method "ToString()"
        var eventSchema = CreateDynamicObject();

        AddPropertyDynamically(eventSchema, "EventAction", "");

        AddMethodDynamically(
            eventSchema,
            "ToString",
            new Func<object>(() =>
            {
                var dictionary = eventSchema as IDictionary<string, object>;
                return (string)dictionary["EventAction"];
            }));

        try
        {
            // Test members for our first object
            eventSchema.EventAction = "This is an EventAction";

            Console.WriteLine(eventSchema.EventAction); // Output: This is an EvenAction

            // Throws an exception if we try to access
            // a non existing member
            eventSchema.NonExistingMethod();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message); // Output: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'NonExistingMethod'
        }

        // Create a second object with a decimal property "Balance"·
        // and a method "Withdraw"

        var bankAccount = CreateDynamicObject();

        AddPropertyDynamically(bankAccount, "Balance", 1000.00M);

        AddMethodDynamically(
            bankAccount,
            "Withdraw",
            new Func<object>(() =>
            {
                var dictionary = bankAccount as IDictionary<string, object>;
                dictionary["Balance"] = (decimal)dictionary["Balance"] - 50.00M;

                return (decimal)dictionary["Balance"];
            }));


        // Test members for our second object
        Console.WriteLine($"Current balance = {bankAccount.Balance}"); // Output: Current balance = 1000.00

        var cash = (decimal)bankAccount.Withdraw();

        Console.WriteLine($"Current balance = {bankAccount.Balance}"); // Output: Current balance = 950.00

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```